# Display the search results 5 at a time

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, search, pagination

I have a page as below to search for words. I want to show 5 results at a time. Then when I hit the show more button, get another 5, and so on so forth.

1-I don't quite know how to include the $_POST['search'] in the javascript.

2-The results I get are sometimes duplicate, which means my "offset" and "limit" definitions are not accurate.

Could you please help me?

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.js" language="javascript" type="application/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $('#showMore').live('click',function(){
        var offset = $('#displayData tr').length;
        var limit  = offset; 
        offset = offset+limit; 
        var search = "?????"; // I don't know how to implemet the search word 
                                   //  in here

     $.ajax({
        url:'getResults.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: {offset: offset, search: search},
        dataType:"text",
        success: function(returnData){
                                $('#displayData').append(returnData);

        }
        })
        })
 </script>


    $search=$_POST["search"];   

    $query2= mysql_query("SELECT *
                FROM table 
                limit 0,5")
    or die(mysql_error());

    ...

<input type="button" id="showMore" value="Show More" />
```

and the Getresults.php (partially)

```
$offset = $_POST['offset'];
$search = $_POST['search'];

$query2= mysql_query("SELECT *
            FROM table
            limit $offset,5")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injecction attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Really, don't do this. SQL injections are around the corner. And use mysqli instead of mysql.

Comment: how is the `search` variable generated?

Comment: @MaxArt: even after I use bind_param()?

Comment: the search variable is generated in a search box. I haven't included that part, because my code is too long.

Comment: @MarcB even after I use bind_param()?

Comment: you don't have any bind_param calls in your code

Comment: @MarcB that would be the next step for me. I wanted to take care of this first!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an "ORDER BY" clause in your MySQL.  That should help keep your results from duplicating when using a limit.  As an example of how to switch your code to MySQLi, it's pretty straightforward.

```
$link = mysqli_connect('DATABASE HOST', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE');

$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id limit $offset, 5";
$results = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('MySQL Error');

while ($results = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    print $results['Answer'];
}
```